# Java desktop application using MVC + Hibernate

Tags: java, mvc, desktop-application, hibernate

I'm developing a Java desktop application. I'm planning to use MVC architecture described at Oracle site: [Java SE Application Design With MVC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html).

I need to store data in database so I decide to use Hibernate as it is very simple 
but there is any tutorial that use Swing+MVC+Hibernate.

It is possible to use them together?

Comment: As a sidenote I would look at javafx, it is the successor to swing.

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't it be possible?

Java Swing is a GUI toolkit, so you'll utilize that framework as part of your `View` layer.

Hibernate is a persistence layer, so you'll utilize that framework as part of your `Model` layer.

Sounds like a good combination of frameworks aligning with the `MVC` pattern.  And by following the `MVC` pattern, you'll be setup to change out or modify those frameworks or layers more easily.

The other advantage of `MVC` is you can focus on each layer, one at a time.  You mentioned looking for a tutorial on `Swing+MVC+Hibernate` but you don't need one.  Follow the MVC tutorials you already mentioned and plugin those frameworks at their appropriate layer.